# How to disable/readonly form while processing/submiting?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, jquery

I am using AJAX to submit forms. I am using following code to submit a form via AJAX.

```
jQuery('form.AjaxForm').submit( function() {        
        $.ajax({
            url     : $(this).attr('action'),
            type    : $(this).attr('method'),
            dataType: 'json',
            data    : $(this).serialize(),
            success : function( data ) {
                        for(var id in data) {   
                          jQuery('#' + id).html( data[id] );                                
                        }
                      }
        });
        return false;
    });
```

#### Question:

I want to disable/readonly while server is processing form data after submit. Form should be normal after submit or any error. Some times user press submit button more than one time and we get unwanted duplicates entries in database.

Any idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This will disable submit button once it's clicked.

```
$('#myform').submit(function(){
      $('input[type=submit]', this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function disable() {
    return false;
}

// Disable form
jQuery('form.AjaxForm').bind( "submit", disable );

// Enable form
jQuery('form.AjaxForm').unbind( "submit", disable );
```

Or if you want to prevent inputs from being modified:

```
// Disable
jQuery('form.AjaxForm input').each( function() {
    jQuery( this ).attr( "disabled", "disabled" );
});

// Enable
jQuery('form.AjaxForm input').each( function() {
    jQuery( this ).attr( "disabled", "" );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Disable the submit button before the `$.ajax` call in your submit handler:

```
$('#yoursubmit').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

And enable it again in the `$.ajax` call's success/error handlers:

```
$('#yoursubmit').attr('disabled', '');
```